# Ruby Code-Cutting (few lines as possible)

Tags: ruby, optimization

So the code below is what I'm trying to cut down to as few lines as possible. Any other ruby tricks out there I could use to shorten it? I appreciate all help anyone can offer.

Article Class:

```
class Article
    attr_accessor :id, :price, :quantity
    def  initialize(id, price, quantity)
        @id, @price, @quantity = id, Float(price), quantity.to_i
    end 
end
```

Order Class:

```
class Order
    def initialize(name)
        @a, i = [], 0
        input = File.open(name, "r")
        while(id = input.gets.chomp)
            j, price = 0, input.gets.chomp
            while(j<@a.length)
                if(@a[j].id.eql?(id.to_i))
                    @a[j].quantity += 1     
                end 
            end
            else
                @a[i] = new Article(id,price,1)
                i+=1
            end 
         end 
     end

    def orderCost
        sum = 0
        @a.each { |e| sum+=(e.price * e.quantity)}
        sum = ((sum*1.07) + 2.99)
    end

    def displaySelectArticles
        min, max = @a[0], @a[0]
        @a.each do |e|
            if(min.cost > e.cost)
                min = e
            end
            if(max.cost < e.cost)
                max = e
            end
            sum += e.cost*e.quantity and q += e.quantity
        end
        puts "Min: #{min.cost} | Max: #{max.cost} | Avg: #{Float(sum)/q}"
    end 
end
```

Comment: Or if you see a better way to formulate this code, by all means let me know. I'm trying to be as efficient as possible with this code.

Comment: You shouldn't be worrying about code size unless you're golfing. Worry more about it's readability.

Comment: Are you aware of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ?  That may be a better place to ask this type of question.

Comment: Do try and avoid doing things like `@a, i = [], 0` where it's not clear what's being assigned to what. Ruby has ways of expanding things on you when you're not paying attention: `a, b = c` is valid code and might assign to both `a` and `b`. Or just `a`. It *depends*. Also give these things actual names. `@a` is utterly meaningless, same with `i`. If this variable is being used on more than a few lines of code, give it meaning.

Comment: Ruby also strongly encourages people to use names like `order_cost` with no capital letters. Class names are like `OrderCost` and constants `ORDER_COST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did my best here but your initialize method didnt make any logical sense to me. Hopefully this can at least guide you into the right direction. **Disclaimer**: None of this was tested and I wrote it off of what methods I could remember.

```
class Order
def initialize(name)
    @a, i = [], 0
    File.readlines(name) do |line|
        # This while loop makes no sense to me
        # Seems like a surefire infiniteloop because if id = 3, it is always true
        # Maybe you meant to do an operator like == for comparison
        while(id = line)
            j, price = 0, line
            while j < @a.length
                @a[j].quantity += 1  if(@a[j].id.eql?(id.to_i))
            end
        else
            @a[i] = new Article(id, price, 1)
            i += 1
        end 
    end 
end

def orderCost
    # I would probably make this two lines because its unreadable
    (@a.inject(0) { |accum, e| accum + (e.price * e.quantity) } * 1.07) + 2.99
end

def displaySelectArticles
    min, max = @a[0], @a[0]
    @a.each do |e|
        min = e if min.cost > e.cost
        max = e if max.cost < e.cost
        sum += e.cost * e.quantity
        q += e.quantity # I have no idea how you got a q
    end
    puts "Min: #{min.cost} | Max: #{max.cost} | Avg: #{Float(sum)/q}"
end 
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The Article class needs serious attention because of that jumble of junk where
three variables are assigned at the same time. Split that out into three very
simple assignments:

```
class Article
  attr_accessor :id, :price, :quantity

  def  initialize(id, price, quantity)
    @id = id
    @price = price.to_f
    @quantity = quantity.to_i
  end 
end
```

Using `x.to_f` is preferable to `Float(x)`, it's a gentler approach to
converting. If you're doing financial calculations I'd **stronly** encourage
you to use something like [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)
as floating point numbers are notoriously problematic. $1.99 has a way of
becoming $1.989999423489 which when rounded can appear to "lose" a cent here
or there. The BigDecimal class avoids this by representing values as exact.

The rest is basically attacking the problem of not using [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html)
effectively and instead writing your own routines to do what should be simple:

```
class Order
  def initialize(name)
    @items = [ ]

    File.open(name, "r") do |input|
      while(id = input.gets.chomp)
        price = input.gets.chomp

        # find locates the first matching thing in the array, if any.
        existing = @items.find do |item|
          item.id == id
        end

        if (existing)
          existing.quantity += 1
        else
          items << Article.new(id, price, 1)
        end
     end 
  end

  def item_cost
    # Inject is good at iterating and accumulating
    @items.inject(0.0) do |sum, item|
      sum + item.price * item.quantity
    end
  end

  def item_count
    @items.inject(0) do |sum, item|
      sum + item.quantity
    end
  end

  def order_cost
    item_cost * 1.07 + 2.99
  end

  def display_select_articles
    # minmax_by finds min and max entries based on arbitrary criteria
    min, max = @items.minmax_by { |item| item.price }

    sum = item_cost
    count = item_count

    puts "Min: %f | Max: %f | Avg: %f" % [
      min ? min.cost : 0.0,
      max ? max.cost : 0.0,
      count > 0.0 ? (sum / count) : 0.0
    ]
  end 
end
```

Whenever possible go with the grain, and that means using Ruby's structures and their native methods. The more you deviate from this the more code you'll have to write, and the uglier your code will get. Sometimes you're solving a difficult problem and you have no choice, but this example is not one of those cases. Everything here is simpler if you just do it the Ruby way.